# Listing authors ordered by last_name

Tags: wordpress, author

Ok so I will share the entire code when i get the page to order by last name. I have set up my authors page to display author image websiteand twitter links, To hide them if the user didnt fill it in in the admin. I also have the page to display last_name, first_name but the page is ordering by first name and looks horrible because of this. I tried several times to talk my client out of this but she is set to have it. I have spent way to long on this and need some help... Working Wordpress on windows servers is going to be the death of me ill say that much. This is my code that I know is causing the problem:

```
    `
   <?php
function contributors() {
global $wpdb;
$user_post_count = count_user_posts( $userid );
$authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM wp_users u LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta um ON u.ID = um.user_id WHERE um.meta_key = 'last_name' ORDER BY um.meta_value ASC;");

foreach ($authors as $author) {
if (get_usernumposts($author->ID) >= 1){
echo "<li>";
echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
echo "/\">";
echo the_author_image($author->ID);
echo "</a>";
echo "<br />";
echo '<div>';
echo "<h2><a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/author/";
the_author_meta('user_nicename', $author->ID);
echo "/\">";        
$last_name = get_the_author_meta('last_name', $author->ID);
if ($last_name != null):
the_author_meta('last_name', $author->ID);endif;
$first_name = get_the_author_meta('first_name', $author->ID);
if ($first_name != null):
echo ",&nbsp;"; endif;
the_author_meta('first_name', $author->ID); 
echo ' (' . count_user_posts( $author->ID ) . ')'; 
echo "</a></h2>";
echo "<br />";

// Position/Title of Authors
$position = get_the_author_meta('position', $author->ID);
if ($position != null):?>
<p class="user_cust"><?php echo $position ?></p><?php endif; ?>
<?php
$user_url = get_the_author_meta('user_url', $author->ID);
if ($user_url != null):?>
<p class="user_cust"><a href="<?php echo $user_url ?>" target="_blank">Linkedin Profile</a></p><?php endif; ?>
<?php
echo "</div>";
echo "</li>";
}
}
}
/**
 * Template Name: Author's Page
 * The template for displaying WP_AUTHOR_LIST.
 *
 * Used to display Author's Details on a page.
 * 
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="page">
    <?php include('scroll_to.php'); ?> 
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <h2>Authors</h2>
<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'authors' ); ?>
    <!-- /* Begin Author's Page */ -->
    <div id="authorlist">

      <ul>
        <?php contributors(); ?>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /* End Author's Page */ -->
  </div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

Comment: I am so close i edited my code with my new code the issue is when i remove the foreach loop i only get the admin and he has all the posts in his post_count for some reason. I tried a var_dump($author->ID); but that did nothing when i removed everything inside the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use new WP_User_Query(); and set your role to "contributor" instead? It's much cleaner than what you are doing above.

Also look at this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30977/list-users-by-last-name-in-wp-user-query